# Keep google current user logged accross routes

Tags: php, authentication, google-api, routes, silex

I try to make an web application which use google api for the user system.

Actually, I can only connect my google account to one route, here it is :

```
$app->get('/home', function () use($client,$app){
    if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
        $url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $output = '<a href="'.$url.'">Se connecter </a>';
    } else {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']['access_token']);
        $output = "";
        require "../view/planning.php";
    }

    return $output;
});
```

Here is my $client :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Application de test");
$client->setClientId(MY_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(MY_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
$client->setRedirectUri(MY_REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setAccessType('online');
```

And my question is : how I can keep the current client to the whole application ?
For exemple, if I have this route :

```
$app->get('/accueil', function () use($client){
  if(isset($_GET['code'])){
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  }
  if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
      $url = $client->createAuthUrl();
      $output = '<a href="'.$url.'">Se connecter </a>';
  } else {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
      $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']['access_token']);
      require ('../view/accueil.php');
      $output = "";
  }
  return $output;
});
```

But this route not working, it show me the link to login. I understand that the application cannot get `'code'` from the url, because there is nothing.

I also tried to keep the `'code'` like this :

```
if(isset($_GET['code']) || isset($_SESSION['code'])){
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['code'] = $_GET['code'];
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

How can I keep the user logged ?

Comment: Put the `'code'` in the session.

Comment: It seemes that $_SESSION variables doesn't exist when I'm accessing to another route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a long night, I find the solution.

It seemes like the redirect on 127.0.0.1 is different than redirect to localhost, so session variables are reset.